# Can't pass -extldflags

Tags: go

I'm trying to use extldflags with Go:

```
-ldflags '-extld gcc -extldflags="-headerpad 0x500" -w -s'
```

But go link does not recognize it, it prints the help dialog

```
# command-line-arguments
usage: link [options] main.o
  -B note
        add an ELF NT_GNU_BUILD_ID note when using ELF

  ...

  -extld linker
        use linker when linking in external mode
  -extldflags flags
        pass flags to external linker
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6234#issuecomment-66084513) answer your question?

Comment: Another problem is that "with golang" bit: you did not show the whole command so we need to second-guess what the actual call was.

Comment: Niceeeeeeeeee, I'm missing -linkmode=external @kostix

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for kostix, I've resolved this problem:

```
-ldflags '-v -linkmode=external "-extldflags=-Wl,-headerpad=0x500" -w -s'
```

Mistake I made:

1. Arguments must be quoted completely, including the key name. I only quoted the value
2. -linkmode=external is required to use gcc, -extld itself won't work